# Can't pass mock to the inject mock service

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have service:

```
@Service
class UserService {

   private final Map<AbstractSomeService, CustomEnum> someMap;

   public UserService(List<AbstractSomeService> someService) {
     someService.forEach(service -> someMap.put(service.getCustomEnum(), service));
    }

  public void logicExecution() {
     //code
  }
}
```

When i am mocking as below: i am getting NullPointer:

```
@Mock
private SomeService someService;  // Service which is extended of AbstractSomeService

@InjectMocks
private UserService userService = new UserService(Collection.singletonList(someService))

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
   MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testBrokenJunit() {
  userService.logicExecution(); // NULL POINTER HERE (
}
```

SomeService:

```
@Service
public class SomeService extends AbstactSomeService() {
  
  public CustomEnum getCustomEnum() {
      return CustomEnum.BROKEN_JUNIT_TEST;
  }
  //logic here
}
```

Stack trace is quite simple:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "getCustomEnum()" because "service" is null
```

StackTrace without constructor initialization:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InjectMocksException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'UserService' of type '...'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : Cannot invoke "java.util.List.forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)" because "someService" is null

at 

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)" because "someService" is null
    at UserService.<init>
```

P.S.

When i am using real object of UserService, not a mock everything is ok.

But it doesn't work with @InjectMocks

Comment: try using @MockBean on User reference

Comment: Can you please add the complete test code? Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias added code of 'SomeService', patly updated code

Comment: Please post the stacktrace as well so we can se what is happening.

Comment: I had a similar problem, when one of my Mocks I was injecting was an implementation in the constructor of InjectMocks. If other people have similar problem try to change implementations to interfaces in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your test class (you don't need to initialize `UserService` with a new instance via the constructor, `@InjectMocks` will do that for you):

```java
@Mock
private SomeService someService;

@InjectMocks
private UserService userService;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
   MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testBrokenJunit() {
  userService.logicExecution();
}
```

If this does not work because you have a `List` and not a simple `SomeService` you can do the following:

```java
@Mock
private SomeService someService;

private UserService userService;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
   MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
   userService = new UserService(Collection.singletonList(someService));
}

@Test
public void testBrokenJunit() {
  userService.logicExecution();
}
```

Comment: for the mock initialization i am using open mocks, please check updated code. But i don't belive that it is a problem. Probably problem is related to that Mocks doesn't work in the constuctors

Comment: My bad. Please check my edited answer. You don't need to instantiate `UserService`. `@InjectMocks` will do that for you.

Comment: If i will remove the constructor mockito will say that he didn't find the instance and tried to create it, and got exception

Comment: Check my other possible solution ;)

Comment: Yep it works, but i say it in P.S. ) But it is not a mock, a real object

Comment: But you will always have a real object of `UserService`, even with `@InjectMocks`. And in fact, you should, because that is your system under test.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@MockBean` to create mock objects

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;

@MockBean
private User user;
```

Comment: My bad, changed the view of code, i do pass the abscract class to the constructorm not some DTO